# install apache,php,mysql on AIX5.2

Tags: php, mysql, aix

I just install apache2+,php5.3.2 and mysql5.0+ in AIX5.2, and all above are installed by rpm packages. 
   But I can not find mysql extension on phpinfo page,that means mysql function can't be identified by php while php4 can load the mysql extension.
   how to make it work, thank you?

Comment: Have you checked the php.ini if the mysql extension is possibly just commented out? If yes, just un-comment this line and restart the Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Install php5-mysql extension and load it in your php.ini

```
extension=mysql.so
```

Comment: it seems that there is not php-mysql for aix